# Set innerHTML of box to element of one of multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a website (for fun) that will be an Ultimate Frisbee strategy tutorial (unimportant, but if you were curious, that's what it'll be).

I want the user to be able to select a topic, and then I will be using jQuery to create a moving diagram of a field, but for now, I am trying to have multiple JavaScript arrays, and when the user hits the button "Next", a  < p > tag's innerHTML will change to an element of that array.

However, I want to be able to use only one function in order to cycle through any possible array of instructions. If this made any sense, I'm impressed. If you do know what I mean and have any ideas, please tell me. Here's the code below. It all works except for currentNumber, or much more likely currentArray.

```
var basicManGuide = new Array();
basicManGuide[0] = "First, we will look at the handlers. The handlers are the two people who will typically have the disc.";
basicManGuide[1] = "Volvo";
basicManGuide[2] = "BMW";
var currentNum = 0;
document.getElementById("basicMan").onclick = function() {
    var currentArray = basicManGuide.slice();
    document.getElementById("menuStuff").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("buttons").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("players").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = currentArray[currentNum];
    ++currentNum;
}
document.getElementById("cancel").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("menuStuff").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("buttons").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("players").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("next").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = currentArray[currentNum];
    ++currentNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentArray` is only in the click handler for basicMan (local scoped).  Move that variable outside of the click handler for it to be available to the other events as a global variable.

Obviously, there other areas that need to be addressed, but this should answer your question.  (E.g., why slice the array when you are not passing in indices to slice?)

```
var basicManGuide = new Array();
basicManGuide[0] = "First, we will look at the handlers. The handlers are the two people who will typically have the disc.";
basicManGuide[1] = "Volvo";
basicManGuide[2] = "BMW";
var currentNum = 0;

var currentArray = basicManGuide.slice(); // <-- this was moved.

document.getElementById("basicMan").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("menuStuff").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("buttons").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("players").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = currentArray[currentNum];
    ++currentNum;
}
document.getElementById("cancel").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("menuStuff").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("buttons").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("players").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("next").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = currentArray[currentNum];
    ++currentNum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually needed that line in the function, but you had the right idea. Thank you again.